# AWS ALB DNS is not reachable

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

New to AWS.

I setup ECS and create a task with ALB. Running python Django application in ECS task on port 8000, and ALB shows `healthy` on status based on health endpoint.

When I try to run `curl http://<DNS_ALB>/<healthcheck endpoint>` its not able to return any data.

ALB shows `healthy` means that `health check endpoint` is reachable from ALB to ECS container.

There is not specific security, I am using all default VPC and Security group. Default security group has `ALL` inbound and `ALL` outbound open.

I know I have to change the security and all, but just trying to learn with default if all things works, then will add more security.

ALB is associated with `sg-db32a7a1` StorageGroup.

[image: ALB SG]

This SG has all in/out open for all ports.

[image: Inbound]

[image: Outbond]

Comment: What exactly is the security group?

Comment: @Marcin added screenshot for the SG.

Comment: what does ALB returns? any HTTP return code? and also can you share target group details as well.

Comment: "not able to return any data" isn't a specific error. Please provide the exact details of the error. Do you get a timeout error? A 50x error? What is the HTTP status code and any specific error message that comes with it?

Comment: got it solve, open inbound 80 port and that work, `ALL` inbound was open only from other security group not from `0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration only allows traffic from a certain security group in the rule set.

[image: At first sight, it looks like all traffic is allowed]

However, scrolling to the side reveals that there is a limitation on the source:

[image: Actually, there is a "source" value set]

I solved the problem by adding two new rules to allow IPv4 and IPv6 traffic.